# How do I specify col_types using read_csv in ldply()?

Tags: r

R 3.60, Windows 10

I'm reading in a bunch of .csv files (001.csv...332.csv) and the contents into a dataframe.  I'm using read_csv in ldply to accomplish this.  It works great, except on some of the files where it can't guess what the proper column type is until after the 1000 line default.  I could increase the number of lines, but I think a more efficient way would be to explicitly define the col_types.

I've tried to do this, but I can't figure out the correct way to code it.

Here's what I had originally.  It works except for the files with that it can't guess the correct atomic class because it's all NA values until after 1000 lines:

```
dat_csv = ldply(myfiles, read_csv)
```

**Here's what I've tried so far :**

```
dat_csv = ldply(myfiles, read_csv(myfiles, col_names = TRUE, col_types =  
               cols(
               Date = col_date(format = ""),
               sulfate = col_double(),
               nitrate = col_double(),
               ID = col_double()
               )))
```

**I get this error :**

> Error in fs[[i]](x, ...) : attempt to apply non-function

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Just to clarify, the issue is unrelated to your use of `col_types`. The actual problem is that you’re attempting to call `read_csv` on all `myfiles` inside the `ldply` call, instead of passing the function itself to `ldply`. Unrelated, by the plyr package is essentially deprecated and replaced by new tidyverse packages. In this case, `ldply` is replaced by `map_dfr`.

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the answer!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to test it but I think your call should look like this:

```
dat_csv = ldply(
  myfiles, 
  read_csv, 
  col_names = TRUE, 
  col_types = cols(
    Date = col_date(format = ""),
    sulfate = col_double(),
    nitrate = col_double(),
    ID = col_double()
  )
)
```

You could also try:

```
dat_csv = ldply(
  myfiles, 
  read_csv, 
  col_names = TRUE, 
  col_types = "Dddd"
)
```

You just append the arguments for the `read_csv()` function in the call to `ldply`. The documentation states:

> ldply(.data, .fun = NULL, ..., .progress = "none", .inform = FALSE,
>   .parallel = FALSE, .paropts = NULL, .id = NA)

where

> ...     other arguments passed on to .fun

Comment: Thank you!  That's it...knew it was something easy...learned something new!  Cheers!